# Help the moderators and use your flags and votes?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm going on a holiday for three weeks and since Nathan is fairly busy at work, Greg needs your help to moderate the site.

So to anyone with 500+ rep: **vote to close questions when they are off-topic, not constructive or are generally poor.**

Even if you don't have 500 rep, you can always **flag questions or answers for moderator attention** and have us clean them up.

Don't let the site depend on just us, we're supposed to be human error handlers, not police officers that have to uphold the law for everyone! **So use your votes!**

Comment: Great timing, Ivo! :-) I'm also traveling for the next three weeks & won't be around the site.

Comment: Uhoh we best notify the team then!